# 'typeof Subscription': prototype, EMPTY

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting the bellow error for returning an subscription objec.

ERROR:--------
Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'typeof Subscription': prototype, EMPTY

My code is :

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  user :{id:number, name:string};

  private paramSubscription = Subscription;

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user={
    id: this.route.snapshot.params['id'],
    name: this.route.snapshot.params['name']
    };
     this.paramSubscription = this.route.params.
     subscribe(
       (params:Params) => {
         this.user.id=params['id'],
         this.user.name=params['name']
       }
     );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.paramSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi guys I got my mistake its nothing but declaration of my Subscription. code should be like.....

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  user :{id:number, name:string};

  private paramSubscription:Subscription;

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user={
    id: this.route.snapshot.params['id'],
    name: this.route.snapshot.params['name']
    };
     this.paramSubscription = this.route.params.
     subscribe(
       (params:Params) => {
         this.user.id=params['id'],
         this.user.name=params['name']
       }
     );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.paramSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer. Doing so will help others who read this question in future. Btw, thanks for the answer (+1)